# How can I access the call log of mobile phone in Angular app?

Tags: angular

I need access the call log, if use the app with mobile (Android or IOS). It is possible?

Comment: At least for Android, I would implement that with a special link in HTML recognized by a matching listener I added to my WebView. I would then do a service call from my angular app to this special link. After recognizing that link on the Android side, that listener would deliver the call log of the phone to the service client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access native mobile features from Angular web application, You need to create a Cordova/ Phonegap/Ionic  app with angular o read call logs